# select 2 js return data not select when mouse click or enter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

When my select field loads, it successfully renders. Once I type at least the two character, it successfully pulls items from the server and lists them as options. However, if I try to select one of them, nothing happens. The drop-down popup stays open. Nothing gets put in the actual field. There are no errors in the JavaScript console. Its like I didn't click anything.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cusName").select2({
    placeholder: '--- Select Item ---',
    //allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
      url: '<?php echo base_url();?>search',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      processResults: function(data) {

        console.log(data)

        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });

  $(".cusName").on('change', function() {
    var data = $(".cusName").select2('data')[0];
    console.log(data);
    $("#cus_id").val(data.customer_id);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <select class="cusName form-control" name="cusName"> </select>

<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cus_id" name="cus_id" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

since your problem was not ajax call as per your description i replaced it with the hardcoded values see below code snippet, if it works as you wanted it to

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cusName").select2({
    placeholder: '--- Select Item ---',
    allowClear: false
  });

  $(".cusName").on('change', function() {
    var data = $(".cusName").val();
    console.log(data);
    $("#cus_id").val(data);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="cusName form-control" name="cusName">
<option value="">select Any</options>
<option value="apple">apple</options>
<option value="mango">mango</options>
<option value="juice">juice</options>
</select>

<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cus_id" name="cus_id" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: already added but not working. select value not selected or any thing. just stack like image

Comment: Mr. Omer Aslam , i implemented your logic i. t's okay. But still stack, may be my framework other JavaScript problem.i did't find it.

Comment: yeah thats y i was asking for any link where i could see it working  and find the problem , can you go to view source and copy paste in the question